# JMeter Get Body Data before Sending

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, beanshell

for example i have http body data like this

```
{
  "signature" : "${signatureCreate}",
  "paramA"  : "1A02",
  "paramB"  : "aaa",
  "paramC"  : "asass"
}
```

how could i get all params (paramA, paramB, paramC) in my BeanShell Preprocessor? i have to get all these 3, encrypt it, and put it back in "signature" param

i also tries using JSR223 PreProcessor like this (only to try to get the paramA value, but still no luck)

```
def body = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())
vars.put("signatureCreate", body.paramA);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: what's your encryption mode? what did you try?

Comment: my mistake, my concern in this question is only to get all these 3 params.. updating the question

Comment: @user7294900 question edited.. please kindly check :)

Comment: If it's in your request why not put variables and then use it as "paramA" : ${paramA},

Comment: no, i want to get paramA (and also paramB, paramC) value, encrypt it, and using it as "signature" param

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine (given you choose Groovy in the "Language" dropdown), just add [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to your Test Plan, you will be able to see `signature` variable value in the "Response Data" tab of the Debug Sampler

[image: JMeter Response Data JMeter Variable]

More information: [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)

Comment: well it's appeared correctly in the debug sampler.. but why i can't put it back in body data? its "signatureCreate" not "signature" btw sorry for the typo